# Angular/router v10.1.6 - router navigation unique ID is always 1 and never changes. And other router.events.pipe anomalies

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

In my Angualr 10.1.6 web app I set the `RouterModule` in the following manner:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: PageHomeComponent },
    { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component }], { enableTracing: true })
```

The html templates of both `PageHomeComponent` and `Page1Component`, contain the same selector:

```
<app-view-loader></app-view-loader>
```

This selector refers to a unique common component, the `view-loader` Component, which contains several sub-components used to manage the whole UI of the web app.
Navigating the app and changing the path (passing from "/home" to "/page1") a different component is loaded (`From PageHomeComponent to Page1Component`). But both components refer to the same view, that is `view-loader`. Simply, using `*ngIf` directive in view-loader, the app shows and hides the right sub-components based on the current URL selected.

First Issue:
navigating the app, after changing the URL and passing form **/home** (`component: PageHomeComponent`) to **/page1** (`component: Page1Component`) the unique ID that the router assigns to every navigation, never changes. It always keeps the same value: 1.

Over the first app load, I see the following, in Debug Console:

```
- NavigationStart { id: 1... }
- RoutesRecognized { id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/home' ... } 
- ...
- NavigationEnd { id:1...}
```

Once navigated to the url "/Page1", I see the follow:

```
- NavigationStart { id: 1, url: '/page1', navigationTrigger: 'imperative', restoredState: null ...}
- RoutesRecognized (id: 1 ...)
- NavigationEnd { id:1...}
```

... And so on...
The unique ID the router assigns to every router navigation, never changes.

This is the first anomaly.

The second issue occurs when I press the browser's `back/forward buttons`. In this circumstance, the value of the field `navigationTrigger` remains 'imperative' and `restoredState` is null.

Finally, the third problem occurs when I debug the following piece of code, included in the constructor of the container component **view-loader**, every sub-views of the app refer to.
Here's the code:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {   
    this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter(
        (event: NavigationEvent) => {
          return(event instanceof NavigationStart);
        }
      )
    )
    .subscribe(
      (event: NavigationStart) => {
        console.log(event);      
     }
   );
```

During debugging, each time the URL changes and the `"filter"` function is called, the object `event: NavigationEvent` gets only the type `NavigationEnd`. I never see the NavigationEvent object to assume the type `NavigationStart` and neither all the other types referring to the different events of the pipeline.
Probably that's why the piece of code "return(event instanceof NavigationStart)" never returns a NavigationStart object to the subscribe method. Moreover, the **subscribe** method is never called during debugging.

In the end, NavigationEvent is always NavigationEnd even if we have before seen that in the debug console, all events (NavigationStart, ..., ChildActivationStart, ActivationStart, ... NavigationEnd) are triggered.

Does anybody have an idea of why that occurs?
Thanks.
E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue n. 1:
Navigating app, after changing URL, the unique ID that router assigns to every navigation, never changes. It's always 1.

Solution:
To keep trace of a complete set of navigation info while opening one or more routed components in the app, it is not enough matching paths to related components in the Routes array of the app's routing-module.
To move from a path destinaton to another generating new identifiers, (even if the activated app component can be always the same) you have to put a routerLink in the anchor tags of templates or to use router.navigate() method in typescript code.
For example, if you type URL directly in the browser's navigation bar, navigation unique id doesn't change. Similarly, using tags without routerLink directive in the templates, it comes to produce the same result. Unique id never change during navigation.

Issue n. 2:
Pressing browser's back/forward buttons, the value of field "navigationTrigger" remains 'imperative' and "restoredState" is null.

Solution:
Usage of routerLink in app's templates or invoking router.navigate() method to change app views, fixes this second issue too, exactly like the first one. Field "navigationTrigger" gets value "popstate" and "restoredState" correctly keeps trace of navigation previous states.